# Getting 502 error when trying to set up SSL on EC2 instance via Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up an SSL certificate on an EC2 instance I've installed Wordpress on, using Cloudfront and Route 53, but I'm getting a 502 error in the browser when I head to the URL. I'm not using ELB as I'm not expecting the traffic to be very high (at least for a while). Anyone know what the issue is?

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Request URL:https://react.edbiden.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:502 
Remote Address:54.230.11.194:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
content-length:587
content-type:text/html
date:Sun, 13 Aug 2017 10:45:32 GMT
server:CloudFront
status:502
via:1.1 d10e0115903b50001036753d910516ef.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:YWp5HN-1zbO56PxkmH_TIBYFtQ4sO1LnvmYk4wjnrTfuXKP0RHLxnQ==
x-cache:Error from cloudfront
```

In Route 53 I've got A records for IP4 and IP6:

```
Alias: Yes
Alias Target: d2dzwf20h9q46z.cloudfront.net.
Routing: Simple
```

In Cloudfront:
[image]
[image]

EC2 settings: 
[image]

Would be super grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change Origin Protocol Policy to "HTTP Only".
Otherwise CloudFront tries to connect to the EC2 instance via HTTPS which will probably fail.

Comment: OP asked for SSL connection

Comment: Yeah, this just gives a different error / problem - chrome calls it a "mixed security" or something, because cloudfront is secure, but the EC2 isn't. You can see the elements of the website (in the wrong layout), but it's not a workable solution.

Comment: If everything that receives the user is served by CloudFront and CloudFront is secure there shouldn't be any issue. Why is somethin served from EC2 instead from CloudFront?

Comment: this saved my life! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the SSL certificate mismatch. You are using a self-signed certificate in the Origin server (EC2 instance) but as per AWS "For origins other than ELB load balancers, you must use a certificate that is signed by a trusted third-party certificate authority, for example, Comodo, DigiCert, or Symantec."
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html

You can try to use Let's encrypt certificate in the instance.

Comment: So Amazon doesn't support AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) for EC2 direct? You have to use a Elastic Load Balancer or provide your own SSL certificate? Seems strange. Thanks for the Let's encrypt tip... I'll check it out

Comment: @EdBiden Yes, ACM certificates cannot be used directly/installed on instances and can be used with ELB, CloudFront etc.

Comment: @EdBiden not strange, it's part of the security model.  You never have access to the certificate's private key, with ACM, and you'd need that to install and use a cert on your EC2 instance.  Note that Let's Encrypt will **not** issue a cert for your EC2 instance's default `*.compute-1.amazonaws.com` hostname.  You need to point a hostname in DNS from one of *your* domains to the EC2 instance and get a cert for that hostname, e.g. for the site `example.com` you might use `origin.example.com` as the hostname for the origin server.  Change CloudFront origin config to use this new name, also.